# csv.field_size_limit not worked

Tags: python, csv

why this error cant be handled? i already tried all of solution in stackoverflow about this problem using field_size_limit, but not worked. here is my code

```
import sys
import csv

csv.field_size_limit()

with open('data_latih_jokowi_negatif.csv', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as file:
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(file))
#del(readCSV[1664], readCSV[1663])
progress = 0

result = readCSV
```

and this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleandoublesentences.py", line 7, in <module>
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(file))
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call `field_size_limit()` with the new limit.

```
csv.field_size_limit(10000000)  # 10 megabytes, give or take
```

Comment: the error changed 
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long :(

Comment: @Trya Sovi Kartikasari: Then use a smaller number.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Switched to a smaller number - 10 megs per field ought to be enough

Comment: still _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (10000)

Comment: That means you've set the limit to 10,000, which is less than the original 131,072.